# fastify does not work on android emulator

Tags: api, express, android-emulator, fastify

I tried to use fastify with the android emu and I could not reach it with a GET request from the browser. I also tried express and it worked perfectly fine. I am a bit confused why express works and fastify does not. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `host` parameter:

```
fastify.listen({ host: '0.0.0.0' })
```

It is written multiple times in the docs:

- https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#listen
- https://github.com/fastify/fastify#note

Comment: yeah sry my fault.

thank you for your time!